# Get cell color of conditionally formatted cell

Tags: excel, vba, format, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to get the cell color using the VBA script

```
Public Function GetCellColor(cell As Range) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    GetCellColor = cell.Interior.Color
End Function
```

This works for manually formatted cells.  But if I use a conditionally formatted cell it just shows the value of the cell with no format.

So When I try to use this VBA below which supposed to find conditionally formatted cells. But it gives me a "#VALUE!" error.  What am I doing wrong, on the script below?

```
Function GetCellColor(cell As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    GetCellColor = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Function
```

Comment: It will all be clear after you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat) which you should have done in the first place.

Comment: What are you expecting from the function (as a string)? Something as `Red`, `Yellow` etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a UDF that will give you cell fill color **(including the fill color from Conditional Formatting)** without that ***#VALUE error*** that you mentioned.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CellFillColor(target As Range, Optional returnFormat As String = "IDX") As Variant
Dim retArray()
Dim rowCounter As Long
Dim colCounter As Long
Dim colorValue As Long
'    Application.Volatile
    If TypeName(target) = "Range" Then
        ReDim retArray(target.Rows.Count - 1, target.Columns.Count - 1)
        For rowCounter = 0 To target.Rows.Count - 1
            For colCounter = 0 To target.Columns.Count - 1
                colorValue = Evaluate("useDF(" & target.Cells(rowCounter + 1, colCounter + 1).Address & ")")
                Select Case UCase(returnFormat)
                    Case "RGB":
                                retArray(rowCounter, colCounter) = _
                                                                    Format((colorValue Mod 256), "00") & ", " & _
                                                                    Format(((colorValue \ 256) Mod 256), "00") & ", " & _
                                                                    Format((colorValue \ 65536), "00")
                    Case "HEX":
                                retArray(rowCounter, colCounter) = _
                                                                    "#" & _
                                                                    Format(Hex(colorValue Mod 256), "00") & _
                                                                    Format(Hex((colorValue \ 256) Mod 256), "00") & _
                                                                    Format(Hex((colorValue \ 65536)), "00")
                    Case "IDX": retArray(rowCounter, colCounter) = colorValue
                    Case Else: retArray(rowCounter, colCounter) = colorValue
                End Select
            Next colCounter
        Next rowCounter
        CellFillColor = retArray 'IIf(target.CountLarge = 1, retArray(0, 0), retArray)
    End If
End Function

Private Function useDF(ByVal target As Range) As Variant
    useDF = target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Function

'in Immediate Window
'Range("G16").Interior.Color=13551615<-IDX value
```

It can also be found on my [GitHub](https://github.com/4R3B3LatH34R7/CellFillColor).

It was based on **Jaafar Tribak**'s code that he shared on [mrexcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-displayformat-in-a-udf.1154593/).

I hope this helps.
Feel free to take it apart and/or rearrange it as above code was written for giving more choices to the user thereby making it (unnecessarily?) longer.

Answer (score 2):

### Return Conditional Formatting Colors With a UDF

- The following workaround is based on the first answer to this question by **Nay Lynn**. Thanks for sharing.

[image]

```vb
Function GetColorCf(ByVal RangeCF As Range) As Variant
    
    Application.Volatile
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = RangeCF.Worksheet
        
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = RangeCF.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = RangeCF.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data(): ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, ColorValue As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            Data(r, c) = ws.Evaluate("GetCellColorCfVba(" _
                & RangeCF.Cells(r, c).Address & ")")
        Next c
    Next r
    
    GetColorCf = Data

End Function

Private Function GetCellColorCfVba(ByVal cell As Range) As Long
    With cell.Cells(1) ' ensure single cell
        Dim ColorValue As Long: ColorValue = .DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        If ColorValue = 16777215 Then
            If .DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
                ColorValue = 0
            End If
        End If
    End With
    GetCellColorCfVba = ColorValue
End Function
```